# Add a checkbox in plugin options page and make it actually work

Tags: plugins, admin, options

My code:

```
function afi_checkbox_field_0_render(  ) { 

$options = get_option( 'afi_settings' );
?>
<input type='checkbox' name='afi_settings[afi_checkbox_field_0]' <?php checked( $options['afi_checkbox_field_0'], 1 ); ?> value='1'>
<?php 
}
```

Now I want to check if the checkbox is checked then show a column, or else hide.

Somethink like:

```
function custom_columns($columns) 
{ if ( the checkbox is checked)
          $columns['the_column'] = 'The Column';
          return $columns;
} else { (hide the column)
   unset($columns['the_column'])
   return $columns;
}
add_filter('manage_posts_columns' , 'custom_columns');
```

Comment: If you are adding an option using Options API, as it seems you are doing, what is the problem of checking that option in the same way you are doing in `afi_checkbox_field_0_render()`? I don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your checkbox state is saved in `$options['afi_checkbox_field_0']`. You can check this setting anywhere using the following code:

```
$options = get_option( 'afi_settings' );

if ( ! empty( $options['afi_checkbox_field_0'] ) ) {
    // Checkbox checked
} else {
    // Not checked
}
```